# How can we resolve the area vector of a 2-D surface into its components?

Tags: vectors, area

If we take a triangle marked by the coordinates (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1), as follows:
[image: Triangle]

It appears that if we take the area of this surface to be a vector quantity, it is equal to the sum of three other area vectors which seem to have a vague relationship with the figure.
Those three area vectors represent triangles whose vertices are the origin and the intercepts made by the figure with the axes.
[image]

Why is this true? Why does the vector sum of "shadows" make up the complete area?

Comment: By shadows you mean projections on xy,yz,zx planes?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_area) may be of interest.  You may also want to look at [Cauchy's area formula](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.05815.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

When you say "take the area of this surface to be a vector quantity", I suppose you mean to represent the area with a vector $\mathbf v$ in the direction normal to the surface and with magnitude being the area?

> **Theorem:**
>
> If a triangle has vertices $A$, $B$, and $C$, then its area is given by $$\text{Area } = \frac 12 |\vec {AB} \times \vec{AC}|$$

Of course, the cross product of two vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ returns a vector that is perpendicular to both $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$. It follows that the "area as a vector quantity" that you want is precisely

$$\vec{Area} = \frac 12 \vec {AB} \times \vec{AC}$$

Now, going back to the question you were asking, if we let

$$\vec {OA} = \mathbf a \qquad \vec {OB} = \mathbf b \qquad \vec {OC} = \mathbf c$$

then the area of the slant surface $ABC$ as a vector is given by

\begin{align}
\vec{Area}(ABC) & = \frac 12 \vec {AB} \times \vec{AC} \\
& = \frac 12 (\mathbf b - \mathbf a) \times (\mathbf c - \mathbf a) \\
& = \frac 12 \mathbf b \times \mathbf c - \frac 12 \mathbf b \times \mathbf a - \frac 12 \mathbf a \times \mathbf c \\
& = \frac 12 \mathbf b \times \mathbf c + \frac 12 \mathbf a \times \mathbf b + \frac 12 \mathbf c \times \mathbf a \\
& = \vec{Area}(OBC) + \vec{Area}(OAB) + \vec{Area}(OCA)
\end{align}

which is what you wanted.